# Automaticly regeneration WSDL after update with AXIS 1.4

Tags: java, maven, axis, java2wsdl

So i have w java project with AXIS 1.4 generated WSDL on eclipse
usually when i update a webService java class, i have to manually regenerate the new WSDL on eclipse before creating the new war file with maven clean install

Is there a way to make this process automtic => the new updated WSDL regenerate automaticly when running maven clean install?

these are the dependencies i have for axis
i'm using create web service wizard of eclipe to generate the wsdl

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your pom.xml. Are you using any maven plugins to generate the files?

Comment: Hi, i'm using eclipe web service creation wizard to generate wsdl files from java classes

Comment: Could this plugin do the job for you automatically perhaps? https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-java2wsdl-plugin.html

Comment: actually i can't use axis2 because i have to generate RPC/encoded for the webservices, and axis2 do not support it

Comment: It should also be available for axis 1.x: https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/maven/java2wsdl/plugin-info.html

Comment: i added the plugin in my pom.xml .Do you have any idea on how tu use it th automaticly generate the wsdl when java class is updated?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to generate only on changes, but you can define an `execution` to always run the plugin when you compile your project. For that you should lookup how maven plugin configuration works.

Comment: unfotunatly this plugin does not seem to be working anymore, is there another way to do the automation? i tried to find other version of this plugin but i could'nt find any

Comment: define 'not working' ?